# Asking SQL schema by FOIA

Tags: mysql, schema, security

I've sent FOIA requests to various public institutions in my area.

I'm only asking for the schema of the SQL databases their financial services might be using (column name for every table for every database).

I'm getting answers along the line that what I'm asking for is a security risk, therefore the organization will refuse my request.

I'm not a DBA. I use MySQL to process data in the public interest, but am only beginner level. I'd like to understand exactly how knowing only the schema of an SQL database could be a security risk. The general guidelines detailed [in the answer to this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8578/what-are-the-first-necessary-actions-needed-to-help-secure-a-databases-schema) don't mention it.

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Comment: When you say "schema", are you talking about the data model (i.e. just the DDL required to create the tables)?  Or including the data as well?  Either one is likely to be problematic from a security standpoint but the data is obviously a bigger risk.

Comment: I'm curious of what use to you (or the public) are the schemas of SQL databases of financial services of various public institutions. If they make any data public, their schemas will be obvious; if they don't, there must be a reason why that is so.

Comment: By schema I mean only the data model, not including data. In my request, I gave an example with `mysqldump -d`. The reason for asking is because I previously asked an export of their database for the amounts payed to their suppliers in recent years. That request was refused on the grounds that it was too complicated to execute. So I asked for the schema to demonstrate, with a precise SQL query, that it was not that complicated and to use that query in a future FOIA request.

Answer (score 3):

Let's suppose the institution does send me a listing of all the tables and their columns.  Even though I don't have the actual data, I can now attempt social engineering attacks to convince insiders into giving me whatever data I want.

The request would sound much more legitimate, because I could ask for very specific pieces of information using the actual table names. If I were to find someone with access to the database and convince them that I'm a higher-ranking employee (e.g. their manager or the CEO), I could make a legit-sounding request for sensitive information.

You would be surprised how often this happens in a corporate environment. Just having the metadata for a database exposed can be a big security risk.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @andba77. A social engineering scenario did not occur to me and makes sense.

Comment: Would they use this trick to be able to fool people? Lots of people give away their username and password or give somebody access to their PC just because somebody knows the right words.

Answer (score 1):

When you know the names of the tables and fields then you are able to craft attacks on their database. The famous 'SQL injection' becomes easier when you know how the data is stored. At the same time you see what information they store. Like they say: *Data is one of the biggest assets of a company*.

Comment: The databases I'm interested in are not on the web. From what I understand, a SQL injection can only be run through web page input. Am I undestanding correctly?

Comment: You are right but it is not because it is not on the internet that it is not on the intranet. I admit my reply is not perfect but I cannot see any other reason.